# Setting default value of a column while generating active record model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add devise authentication to my app. There will be two types of users, admin and public user. I am trying to achieve this by adding a boolean `admin` column to the `User` model that I am about to generate by doing,

```
rails g devise User admin:boolean
```

How can I set the default boolean value to `false` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with:

```
rails g devise User
```

Then open migration generated by the Devise and add:

```
t.boolean :admin, default: false
```

somewhere inside

```
create_table :users do |t|
  <here goes your code>
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**Best practice is to do it via migration**

```
rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```

It will generate migration for you and then add default: false:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

And then `rails db:migrate`

And the answer of your question

> Q: Setting default value of a column while generating active record model
>
> Ans: You cannot pass default value to rails generate migration